# Can't figure out how to set the values of an array

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and trying to loop through an array to set each element equal to a random number. I am wondering why this works:

```
function randomize() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
    document.getElementById(i).style.paddingTop = random + "%";
  }
}
```

but when I am trying to use an array instead of a variable, doesn't:

```
function randomize() {
  const sortArray = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    let sortArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
    document.getElementById(i).style.paddingTop = sortArray[i] + "%";
  }
}
```

Comment: Because `let sortArray[i] =` is invalid syntax. You can declare a variable, or assign to a property of an existing variable, but not both at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a syntax error. You should remove `let` in the array[i] declaration

```
function randomize() {
  const sortArray = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    sortArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
    document.getElementById(i).style.paddingTop = sortArray[i] + "%";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring sortArray again.
You have already declared sortArray as

```
const sortArray=[];          //sort array is already declared here
  for (let i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
sortArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);  //No need to declare again
 document.getElementById(i).style.paddingTop = sortArray[i] + "%";
}}
```